# Live updating ListView JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I have class:

```
public class Friends implements Runnable{
private ObservableList<String> friendsList;

public Friends() {
    this.friendsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}

public ObservableList<String> getList(){
    return friendsList;
}
public void start(){
     //run thread here
}
@Override
public void run() {
    //update friendList here
}
```

}

In controller i write this:

```
Friends vf = new Friends();
ListView_1.setItems(vf.getList());
vf.start();
```

After that ListView update every second, but i have exception like this: 
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5.
.....

Having read the manual, I understood that we need to refresh UI in FX thread. I have used Platform.runLater(), but UI is slowing down by the end of the stream.

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code (specifically the version where you use `Platform.runLater(...)`)? This should not slow the UI down, unless you are calling `Platform.runLater(...)` very frequently. If you updating periodically, you might consider a [`ScheduledService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html)

Comment: @James_D
In methode
start(){ 
     Thread t = new Thread(this);
      Platform.runLater(t);}
I do this wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. Why are you running your background runnable on the FX Application Thread? You want to run on a background thread, and just schedule the updates to the list on the FX Application Thread. Create a [MCVE] to demonstrate what you are doing, and [edit] your question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your Friends.run runs on a separate thread and updates friendsList there. But this is not allowed. You must update friendList on the FX application thread using `Platform.runLater(() -> { friendsList.setAll(newValue); })`.

You can build newValue in the background thread but setting friendsList MUST be done on the FX application thread.

Answer (score 0):

First create a task class that performs the updation of your friends list

```
public class UpdateFriendsTask extends Task<Void>{ 

    public ObjectProperty<ObservableList<String>> friendsProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public ObservableList<String> friendsList;

    public UpdateFriendsTask (ObservableList<String> friendsList) {

           this.friendsList = friendsList;
           friendsProperty.setValue(friendsList);

    }

    @Override
    public Void call () throws Exception {

        // parallel task to update friends list
        // friendsList.add(...) ....
        // friendsProperty.setValue(friendsList);
        // maybe fetching from a datasource or web service

    }
}
```

and add the following code to your main code

```
// create a list of friends
ObservableList<String> friends = FXCollections.observableArrayList("John", "....");
//create listview to contain friends
ListView listView = new ListView();
// create instance of UpdateFriendsTask to update friends 
UpdateFriendsTask friendsUpdateTask = UpdateFriendsTask(friends);
// bind friendsProperty to listView items property
listView.itemsProperty().bind(friendsUpdateTask.friendsProperty);

friendsUpdateTask.start();
```